# Can't Log in to Ubuntu-one

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-one, login

I get:

```
"OpenID failed
OpenID discovery error: HTTP Response status from identity URL host is not 200. Got status 503"
```

Comment: It worked previously and I am not sure what changed.  I am using Chrome and clicking on the "Login or sign-up" icon on the one-ubuntu.com page.

Comment: Status 503 is website unavailable. Launchpad is currently down, I assume Ubuntu One uses the same servers.

Comment: I'm getting this as well, so i'm leaving this open temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status 503 is website unavailable.

Launchpad is currently down, I assume Ubuntu One uses the same servers.

Comment: All of the Ubuntu web sites are currently down, with the exception of the ones not hosted on their servers like Ask Ubuntu.